# Program compatibility pop-up issue

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-preview

I bought a new lappy and got windows 8 pro with it ,recently i updated it to 8.1 preview and just from a few days from now i am getting program compatibility pop-ups when i install some new softwares anti-viruses and stuff ; in correspondence one of your threads i tried everything pgedit.msc & opening mmc (where i didnt find local group policy editor) if the problem is related to windows 8.1 preview upgrade please let me know ,also guide me if there is a way to solve the problem or to switch back to earlier version of windows(8pro).

Comment: Your question is hard to read, please improve your formatting.

Comment: If the compatibility pop-ups did not happen with Windows 8 then there are compatibility problem with Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you have installed the software, right click and select **properties**.
2. Select the **Compatibility Tab**
3. Select **Run in Compatibility Mode**, then select the version of windows the software was designed for.
4. Apply the settings

This *should* solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a recovery partition via Windows, before you installed 8.1 then you could restore your machine. [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive)

You could always factory restore your machine is you are unhappy with Windows 8.1

I don't believe the 8.1 is your issue. You probably would have had issue installing the software in Windows 8 period.

Answer (score 0):

Ms changed the way how the GetVersionEx API works, so some tools run into trouble:

**Operating system version changes in Windows 8.1 Preview**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The App developer must add the supportedOS ID into the manifest:

```
<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
```

So call the support of the tools.